# Force WebSphere to Compile Stale JSPs

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1

I'm running WebSphere 6.1.0.5. I updated two JSP files and restarted the app through the admin console. One of them displays correctly and the other persists in showing the outdated version that existed before the change.

Things I have tried:

- Cleared browser history, cookies, cache, all temporary data.
- Checked the JSP compile folder under %wasdir%/profiles/server/temp and found an outdated .class file, deleted it.
- Checked the JSP for no-cache header attributes.
- Verified that WebSphere debug wasn't enabled per [this question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205069/websphere-app-server-not-compiling-jsp-tag-libs).

I would just as soon not reinstall the whole app, if at all possible.

Comment: Check if this is 'stand alone' jsp or is included in some other. If included you need to 'touch' the parent one.

Comment: No, it's a full JSP with head and body, not a JSPF. I access it directly through the URL.